# jquery .show("slide") options

Tags: jquery, show, slide

Here's my code.  It slides in from the left.

```
<script>
  $('#goalHS').click(function() {
  $('div[id^="div-detailed-goal"]').show("slide"); 
  }); 
  $("#redline").click(function() {
    $('div[id^="div-detailed-goal"]').fadeOut("slow"); 
     }); 
</script>
```

Instead of fading in from the left, I want a red line to be drawn and then have the DIV slide in from the top.

How can I get it to do the following?

1. Horizontal red line grows out from center.

> ```
>                 ---
> ```

1. Red line finishes growing:

> ---

1. Content slides in from underneath red line.  COntent does NOT show above red line:

> ---
>
> c.  content, content, content
>
> d.  content, content, content

1. Content finishes sliding in.  Awesomeness ensues!

> ---
>
> a.  content, content, content
>
> b.  content, content, content
>
> c.  content, content, content
>
> d.  content, content, content

I've tried 4 different ways, and I've tried using other js plugin libraries, but I'm not quite that advanced to figure it out.

Comment: You need to do something about our formatting, the question doesnt make sense at all.

Comment: It looks like you need two divs, one for the animated horizontal red line and another for the content. Perform the content load in the callback for the animation of the line.

Comment: I've attempted to format your post--please feel free to roll it back or change it if it does not reflect what you are looking for.